# executing a stored procedure in sqlserver it returns error permission issues

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-server-2008

I have one stored procedure.

I execute SP using `sqlcmd` in remote server but issue is in `windows administrator` account.

It is working fine when i try different user it's not working and returns error.

please check below sqlcmd command and error

```
sqlcmd -S servername -E -d dbname -Q "EXEC [dbo].[sp_name]"
```

Error is

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Server servername, Procedure sap.get_status_data, Line 1 
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_name', database 'dbname', schema 'dbo'.
```

I don't know windows/database administration so if it's problem with window level permission or database level permission.

Please help me if it is windows permission, how to give it or if it is database permission, how to give it.

Comment: --> "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_name'"

Comment: how to give permission for the object sp_name

Comment: search for GRANT EXECUTE

Answer (score 1):

which version of sql server you are using ..

try out this command :

> grant execute on dbo.sproc to youruser ;

The dbo schema contains more that your user sprocs and is to be considered a system (read "internal") schema (with sql2005 and 2008 MS introduces the sys schema containing their new systems stuff)

If you still have objects in the dbo schema, I would advise you to keep on granting them individually or - if you can (and my preference) - migrate them to a new schema.

Comment: the user does not have enough privileges in the database. Make sure the account you're using is a member of the appropriate role.